# Access violation exception importing a c++ dll file into c#

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll

Am trying to use functions from a dll file i built in c++ in c#; below is the c++ .h codes

```
#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged

#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else /* Not BUILDING_DLL */
# define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif /* Not BUILDING_DLL */
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
string DLLIMPORT encrypt(string keeper);
string DLLIMPORT decrypt(string keeper);
}

#endif /* _DLL_H_ */
```

the c++ .cpp codes are below

```
#pragma managed
#include "cenH.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char alphabets[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n',
'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

string encrypt(string keeper)
{
string keep;

string m = keeper;
cout << keeper.length() << endl;
for(int count = 0; count < m.length(); count++)
{
   for(int c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
        if(m[count] == alphabets[c])
        {

                    int counter = c - 8;
                    if(counter < 0)
                    {
                               counter = counter + 26; 
                               keep += alphabets[counter];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                               keep += alphabets[counter];      
                    }
        }    
        else if(m[count] == ' ')
        {
             keep+=".";
             break;
        }

   }//end of second loop

//end first loop
cout << keep << endl;


 return keep;
}

string decrypt(string keeper)
{ 
 //cout << "\n" << endl;   
 string keep;

      string m = keeper;
      for(int count = 0; count < m.length(); count++)
      {
           for(int c = 0; c < 26; c++)
           {
                if(m[count] == alphabets[c])
                {
                            int counter = c + 8;
                            if(counter >= 26)
                            {
                                       counter = counter - 26; 
                                       keep += alphabets[counter];                                                  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                       keep += alphabets[counter];

                            }
                }else if(m[count] == '.')
                {
                      keep+=" ";
                      break;
                }   
           }//end of third loop

      }//end second loop
        //cout << keep << endl;

 return keep;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                   DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                   LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
  switch (reason)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    break;

  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;

  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;

  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
}

/* Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
return TRUE;
}
```

i compile this codes and they dont give errors, i even test run them in a c++ console app by calling the dll file and it works fine but when i call this dll file into my c# programs it give me the AccessViolationException Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. The dll is complied in the MinGW GCC 4.6.2 32-bit and my c# runs on x86(32-bit).can someone please point to me what i have done wrong.

This is how i imported the dll inside my c# code

```
[DllImport("cen.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern string decrypt(String keeper);
string line = decrypt("savethemonkeys");
```

Comment: You cannot pinvoke functions that use C++ classes like std::string as arguments or function return values.  Only simple C types are supported.  The only way to do it is through a C++/CLI wrapper.  That still won't work for a mingw compiled DLL, it has a very different std::string class implementation.  Interop with C++ classes is always very difficult, it doesn't work well in native code either unless *all* of the code is compiled with the exact same compiler version and the exact same C++ standard library.

Comment: I agree with Hans. Your C API isn't a C API if it uses C++ types :-)

Comment: @HansPassant please kindly suggest what i should do to get it work :? should i add classes to the following code or use a different API entirly

Comment: Continued: C++ only supports source code compatibility, there is no binary standard that anybody ever agreed on.  Even the same compiler from the same vendor is usually incompatible between versions.  Like such a DLL built with VS2008 is not usable from a C++ program built with VS2010.  Unless the DLL was carefully designed to avoid such interop incompabilities.  Std::string is certainly out.  The only way forward therefore is to rebuild the DLL with the Microsoft C++ compiler and use a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: @HansPassant okeyi thanks i understand you now.

Comment: @dta: Alternatively, you can change your API to accept primitive C types (e.g. const char* keeper, int keeperLength), which would allow you to use pinvoke without a wrapper (since your C API would then be well-defined across compilers). And the calling convention is probably cdecl (since you declared the prototypes as extern C), not stdcall, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: ...But you still wouldn't be able to return a std::string, so you could also take `char* result, int maxResultLength` parameters, but then it's annoying to do the manual string memory allocation on the C# side.

Comment: okeyi i get it but icould still use the .h and .cpp file and just include them in my code in the visual c++ environment? than creating a new one all over again.

Comment: @Cameron, been a long time since I've done PInvoke, but isn't there a flag that indicates/controls ownership of the memory in a return value?